# How to put record in map of linkedhashmap java or how to create data structure?

Tags: java

How to put record in :

```
Map<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>> fileRecords = new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String,String>>();
```

I have two files in the same format, i have to create the data structure for both of them, and then compare the data structure to identify the differences for each CAID-find the blocks and compare the data.

[image]

So accordingly i tried to read the file line by line. confused of what should i try to put the records in map or in arraylist (I have to follow the insertion order).

Take ID as unique, for unique id, i want to store the corresponding block and data.

Comment: use sql - it would be better

Comment: Sql cannot be used, bcoz I need to read the data from file and even its big file with data around 70K records.

Comment: It looks like you don't really have a key. The three columns seem to be keys. If you don't provide a unique key to a hashmap it will of course override the previous value. Wouldn't adding an extra selfgenerated ID (i.e. autoincremental) column help?

Comment: It's a bit confuse in my head, what do you have, in which format, and what do you want.

Comment: We can't help you with determining your requirements. **You** understand the usage of your data, so **you** should define its structure. In other words: it is not really clear what you are trying achieve; and why so.

Comment: well i think  i would take id as unique value as a key and store the block and data in another map. can it be possible ?

Comment: @TilakMadichetti If he has a single file with that information; what makes you think you are in a position to instruct him that "using a sql database" would be better. You don't know his requirements, you don't know where his data is coming from, and how it needs to be processed? In other words: be careful making such **bold** statements that a technology that is an order of magnitude more complex than reading lines form file into maps ... is "better".

Comment: I have to read a file and in each line i have the data in the above format.

Comment: Actually i was looking to create the data structure for this and traverse the DS accordingly.

Comment: You are not telling us how that data should be used afterwards. As Joao wrote: using MAPs implies that your keys are unique. But they are **not**. Thus you might want to step back and consider using different data structures. But in order to understand how such a data structure should be designed, you have to understand how it will be used later on. And that is something we don't know about.

Comment: Please stop providing more infos in comments. Always update the question instead.

Answer (score 1):

The decision to use a Map or a List or a Set lies on the purpose of the data being read.

- if you need to index the data (e.g. by ID), then use a Map
- else, if you want to iterate through the data in order, I would recommend a List or Set collection. If your dataset does not support duplicates I recommend you a Set, or a List if it will have duplicates.

About the code using Map, the piece of code below groups Block and Data per ID:

```
public void read() {
   Map<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>> fileRecords = new LinkedHashMap<>();
   String id, block, data;

   //while(dataInFile()) {
       // I assume data is read row by row into vars id, block and data

       // get the block map for the just read ID
       LinkedHashMap<String, String> blockRecords = fileRecords.get(id);

       // first Block for the ID
       if (blockRecords == null) {
           blockRecords = new LinkedHashMap<>();
           fileRecords.put(id, blockRecords);
       }

       // read data and block
       blockRecords.put(block, data);
   }
```

This code also allows you to group block and data if the IDs are not sorted in the file.
If the ID is always an integer, I recommend you to use an Integer instead of String. It saves memory and CPU during the matching.

Also, if data in your file is not just these 3 fields, I'd recommend you to use objects instead. Then you will need to be more mindful about the usage of the data to design the object model.

Comment: yes you are right, through list would be better. Can i create source = Map<id, Arraylist<D2>> where
 D2 = ArryayList <D3> and target = Map<id, Arraylist<D2>> where 
 D2 = ArrayList <D3> and then compare the records

Comment: What I meant was to read into List<Record>:
`
    class Record {
        private String id;
        private String block;
        private String data;
        // ...
    }
`
And then use Comparator, Comparable or Iterator to sort the list or iterate through it in the order you want.